# Can I use nm to see the inputs of a funciton in an object file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, nm

I have some object files, and can use the `nm` command to see which objects are contained in the file.

I am interested in knowing what inputs the functions that I can see are expecting.

Is there any way to use `nm` to see this? I've checked the flags listed in the documentation but none of them seem to do what I want.

Comment: AFAIK no, there is other tool c++filt for to demangle c++ function names.

Comment: C++ function names are mangled, and the `-C` parameter demangles them, showing the parameters. C function names are not mangled, therefore it is not possible to determine what their parameters are.